# E2209 Unable to open include file 'System.Internal.StrHlpr.hpp'

Tags: ide, c++builder

I am running Embarcadero RAD Studio 10.1 Berlin Update 2 on Windows 10.

My IDE environment worked fine yesterday. I compiled and build successfully using the IDE. My normal operation before running and debugging my project is to compile a couple libraries and then build my executable. Once that is done, then I'll run the executable to check out the functionality and debug etc.

This morning I compiled my libraries, as I always do, and I received the following error:

```
[bcc32 Error] dstring.h(17): E2209 Unable to open include file 'System.Internal.StrHlpr.hpp'
  Full parser context
    File.cpp(2): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\include\windows\vcl\vcl.h
    vcl.h(10): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\include\windows\vcl\basepch0.h
    basepch0.h(62): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\include\windows\rtl\System.hpp
    System.hpp(1599): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\include\windows\rtl\sysclass.h
    sysclass.h(46): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\include\windows\rtl\dstring.h
```

I have ensured no pending changes exist in my local source and versioning.

I have tried cleaning, recompiling, and rebuilding.

My computer did run a Windows Update this morning. The following two were installed:

- Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1607 for x64-based Systems (KB4015438)
- Update for Microsoft Outlook 2013 (KB3141495) 32-Bit Edition

I also checked out the files at the following referenced path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\include\windows\rtl`
The file dates don't appear to suggest any changes were made recently to these files located withinn the rltl folder.

I have also tried restarting my computer.

What would cause something like this to happen and how would I go about resolving this?

Comment: Does `System.Internal.StrHlpr.hpp` exist on your HDD, in the IDE's search path? Have you tried using a tool like [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor) to see exactly where the compiler is looking for the file?

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you for that tool. Using said tool, the compiler appears to be searching several of my include paths for the file. All results are 'NAME NOT FOUND'. Using Notepad++ and searching all of source, it appears other files look for the `System.Internal.StrHlpr.hpp` file as well. I believe the file should exist at this location: `c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0\include\windows\rtl\System.Internal.StrHlpr.hpp`. What's still unknown to me is what happened to this file? I wonder the following: Would repairing RAD Studio would recreate that file? Is this the best option?

Comment: @RemyLebeau; for further clarity, no, the file does not exist. (My guess is that it did exist yesterday.)

Comment: It should exist in the `$(BDS)\include\windows\rtl` and `$(BDS)\include\osx\rtl` folders. If it does not, try repairing the installation.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you for your input; repairing the RAD Studio installation resolved the issue. Still not sure what caused this as this isn't a new installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.Internal.StrHlpr.hpp` is included in runtime library files when initially installing RAD Studio Berlin 10.1 Update 2.

By running the RAD Studio installer again and clicking repair installation during the process, this missing file is recovered and can again be found in the `rtl` folder: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\include\windows\rtl\` allowing for successful compiling and building.